# What happened when press ctrl+D in while(cin>>i) loop in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am new to C++ and feel a little confused with this question. I use Mac OS X and command "g++ -std=c++11" to compile the code.

May be this question is too broad, I don't know, but if someone can explain with following example please?

```
int temp;
while (cin >> temp) {
    cout << temp << endl;
}
```

When I input

```
1 2 3<ENTER>
```

It prints

```
1
2
3
```

as I expected, and press

```
<CTRL+D>
```

to quit.

But if I input

```
1 2 3<CTRL+D>
```

It prints

```
1D
2
```

following with my input character "3", and then I press

```
<ENTER>
```

the last character "3" will be printed. Then I should press

```
<CTRL+D>
```

again to quit.

And besides, there is a similar example as following:

```
vector<int> list; int temp;
while (cin >> temp) {
    list.push_back(temp);
}
for (auto e : list) {
    cout << e << endl;
}
```

When I input

```
1 2 3<ENTER><CTRL+D>
```

It prints

```
1D
2
3
```

So my question is:

What happened in these three cases then I press

```
<CTRL+D>
```

and

```
<ENTER>
```

?

Why there is a "D" character in the second and third case? And how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Are you sure you fail to press correctly `CTRL+D` and maybe you pushed `D` too? Try again and see if the behaviour is repeated!

Comment: @BiagioFesta This cannot be true since the list is of integers. How can he push "D"?

Comment: "D" is not a character your program prints (it cannot, it only prints numbers). It's something your terminal driver prints.

Comment: @n.m. This post is not a duplicate of the stated post.

Comment: @LiranFunaro I disagree but you always can use the reopen button.

Comment: @n.m He asked why it prints `D`, not what it does or why isn't it working. I can't repoen it, no such button for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to overlapping between the console output and yours.

When you press `ctrl+D`, the console prints `^D` but print a return character (`'\r'`) immediately afterward. This means that everything that will be printed after that, will be printed over the `^D`.

Your program first prints `1`, so it only overlaps the `^`, leaving the `D` intact. Try inserting a two digit number and you will see that the `D` disappears.

Some consoles wipe the line after the return character, but some don't as probably your console does.

## Solutions

(1) You can simply print `'\n'` (`std::endl`) before you start printing the list. This will leave the ugly `^D` in the console but it will not overlap your print.

```
vector<int> list; int temp;
while (cin >> temp) {
    list.push_back(temp);
}
cout << endl; // Print before the list.
for (auto e : list) {
    cout << e << endl;
}
```

(2) You can print an empty line first to delete this print. Just print: `"  \r"` (i.e., two spaces then a return character).

```
int temp;
while (cin >> temp) {
    cout << "\r  \r" << temp << endl; // Print in each line
}
```

Comment: Neither of the solutions seem to work except for the special case of pressing Ctrl-D at the first line of the input.

Comment: @n.m. I've edited the solutions with explicit code to prevent misunderstanding.